# Union date ranges in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Assuming I have a list of date range tuples, what would be the most elegant and efficient way to combine and reduce them?

For example, the following list:

```
('2021-01-10', '2021-01-15')
('2021-01-13', '2021-01-17')
('2021-01-25', '2021-01-30')
('2021-01-17', '2021-01-20')
('2021-02-17', '2021-02-20')
```

The output should be:

```
('2021-01-10','2021-01-20')
('2021-01-25','2021-01-30')
('2021-02-17', '2021-02-20')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
type LIST = List[(String, String)]

def mergeDates(list: LIST): LIST = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: LIST, curr: (String, String), res: LIST): LIST =
    l match {
      case hd::tail =>
        if (hd._1 <= curr._2) {
          loop(tail, (curr._1, hd._2), res)
        } else {
          loop(tail, hd, curr +: res)
        }
      case _ =>
        (curr +: res).reverse
    }

  list.sortBy(_._1) match {
    case hd::tail => loop(tail, hd, Nil)
    case _ => Nil
  }
}

mergeDates(list).foreach(println)
```

This works because the date strings in this format sort correctly in date order. More work is required if more general date formats are allowed.

Comment: I think that's perfect. Thanks