# I want to read data that is stored in the case class, group it by addressid and then print it using another case class

Tags: scala, functional-programming

So I have a file with addressid data along with customer id,from date and to date(date given in days) and it is formatted to give me data as follows:

> List(AddressData(IND0023,ADR000,923,1024), AddressData(IND0032,ADR000,268,395),....)

so now i need the output to come like this:

```
List[(0,ADR003,[IND0001,IND0007],1710,1825),(1,ADR000,[IND0002,IND0004,IND0089],956,1778)...)
Total number of groups: taken from the group count in the above list
```

How do I go about doing this?

```
   object AddressAssignment extends App {

  //Define a case class AddressData which stores the occupancy data
  case class AddressData(
                          customerId: String,
                          addressId: String,
                          fromDate: Int,
                          toDate: Int
                        )
//Case class for output data
  case class addressGroupedData(
                                 group: Long,
                                 addressId: String,
                                 customerId: Seq[String],
                                 startDate: Int,
                                 endDate: Int
                               )
```

EDIT: Re-edited to give more clarity and understanding! :D

Comment: You need to `groupBy` addressid and then have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816484/union-date-ranges-in-scala/68816633) which does something very similar with overlapping date ranges.

Comment: What does `AddressGroupedData.group` signify and how is the value determined? It's the only `Long` in the posted code.

Comment: @Tim I am very new to functional style of programming and I dont understand it very well. Could you rewrite the code based on what I have given above that is if you can and have the time. I do apologise for asking so much.

Comment: @jwvh based on the pdf i have, it doesn't say much about it, I just know that I have to make use of the this case class and show the total number of groups in the output

Comment: So, according to your understanding, if every `AddressGroupedData` element in the result `List` has a `group` value of `0L`, that would be okay?

Comment: @jwvh from my understanding the group holds the data of the addressid, customer id, from and to date.

Comment: The `group` data member is type `Long` so only holds a number somewhere between +-9223372036854775807.

Comment: @jwvh I have asked around for some clarity and I shall get back asap.

Comment: @jwvh So the response I got is that it can be used as a unique identifier of each group since addressId wont be unique.

Comment: But `addressId` **is** guaranteed to be unique. That's how the different `customerId`s are combined.

Comment: @jwvh I gave the same answer and for some reason they said if you can work it out that is well and good.

Answer (score 1):

Well the transition from `List[AddressData]`-to-`List[AddressGroupedData]` is pretty straight forward. (This isn't the most efficient means but it's relatively easy to understand.)

```
val agds: List[AddressGroupedData] =
  occupancyData.groupBy(_.customerId)
               .zipWithIndex
               .map{ case ((cid, ads), idx) =>
      AddressGroupedData(idx.toLong 
                        ,cid
                        ,ads.map(_.addressId)
                        ,ads.map(_.fromDate).min
                        ,ads.map(_.toDate).max)
               }.toList
```

I'll leave `List[AddressGroupedData]` to formatted output for the attentive reader.

However, this *does* leave a few unanswered questions:

- What is `sortedOccupancyData` for? Why is it included in the posted code?
- Why is the `group` element type `Long`? Can the number of `AddressGroupedData` instances really be expected to go beyond `Int.MaxValue`?

Comment: **sortedOccupancyData** is just to give a sample of how the data is coming out after proper formatting from the file. 
**group** element is used to give the total number of groups formed from the operation performed. I need to give the total number of groups formed as part of the answer. Just got this answer once I spoke to the people providing the training. I was in the same confusion as you were. The pdf does not give all the instructions unfortunately.

Comment: your code gives me the output as follows: 
    List(AddressGroupedData(2394,IND0069,List(ADR003),331,433), AddressGroupedData(2500,IND0263,List(ADR005),1703,1791).......... Its not what I was looking for

Comment: The `sortedOccupancyData` explanation makes no sense. The `group` element explanation raises many more questions. So far it looks like the whole point of this exercise is to see how much bogus junk they can feed you.

Comment: **output format**: Please read what I wrote. I provided code to populate a `List[AddressGroupedData]`. I left the _"...formatted output for the attentive reader."_ I was hoping that would include you. After all, changing each `List` element into a formatted `String` of element values, and sending each string to `println()`, is pretty basic stuff. You _do_ know basic Scala, yes?

Comment: Apologies if I am not making sense, I am very new to scala, in fact I finished a course on it last week only. If you are available I can show you the pdf on a separate video chat. Possibly I might have missed something.

Comment: I was shown the output file to see how the result should be and I have modified it. See if that help now! From the people who have done this I heard they used two recursions to get the job done.